# Wait until static data is retrieved from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve username of current user from Firebase Realtime Database, after display it on the screen for some time and then start new activity. Sometimes we cannot retrieve username, because user does not have internet connection. For that case I want to display message on the screen like "Waiting for internet response" and then start listener again. How can I do that? I wrote some code, but method onCanceled never invoked and I guess it is the wrong way to do it.

```
TextView welcome = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

final DatabaseReference nickname = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("nickname");

nickname.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String username = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
        welcome.setText("Welcome back \n" + username + "!");
        nickname.removeEventListener(this);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
                        }
                    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
                };

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        welcome.setText("Waiting for internet response)");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onCancelled` method is called when the server rejects the read operation, typically because your security rules don't allow the user to read the data they're trying to access. So a better message to display there would be:

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    welcome.setText("You do not have permission to access this data");
    Log.e("Firebase", "Unable to read nickname", error.toException());
}
```

---

To display a message that you're waiting for data, you'll want to show that message before starting to load the data and hide it when the data has loaded, or the load has been cancelled.

So something like:

```
final DatabaseReference nickname = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("nickname");

welcome.setText("Loading nickname..."); // 
nickname.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String username = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
        welcome.setText("Welcome back \n" + username + "!");
        nickname.removeEventListener(this);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    };

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        welcome.setText("You do not have permission to access this data");
        Log.e("Firebase", "Unable to read nickname", error.toException());
    }
});
```